# jupyter themes - default theme but width 100%

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am starting to use jupyter themes:

https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes

In order to set a theme, I set the theme, and then start jupyter notebook:

```
jt -t solarizedl -cellw 100%
jupyter notebook
```

However, I would like to preserve the jupyter notebook default settings, and ONLY widen cells to 100%. Therefore, I run the following to restore default, set theme, then launch.

```
jt -r
jt -cellw 100%
jupyter notebook
```

However, that doesn't do anything; my notebook is still a default width and not 100% width of my screen.

Any ideas on how to achieve only 100% cell width using the cmd prompt via jupyter themes?

Answer (score -1):

You have number of options for this:

1. Changing from notebook

> ```
> from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
> display(HTML('<style>.container {width:100% !important;}</style>'))
> ```

2. Creating custom css file under `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` (Jupyter) `~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.css` (iPython) with content:

> ```
> .container {width: 100% !important;}
> ```